# Add space after each link in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I am fetching all anchor tag links via web scraping  and want to print all links with space between them so while console I used "\n" but it is not making space after end of first link and second link text start without space.

Code:

```js
(async() => {
  const html = await axios.get('https://www.xyz');
  const $ = await cheerio.load(html.data);
  let data = []
  $(".div-previews").each((i, elem) => {
    console.log('data::', $(elem).find(".header-text a").text() + "\n"); // show links with space between them
  })();
})
```

Comment: The **cause** is that `.find("a").text()` will combine all the texts for all the `a`s into a single text - that's how jquery `.text()` works.  You need to "loop" each "a", not using a single `.text()` call against all of them. The simplest way to "loop" and get the text for each is via `.map`, as provided in the provided answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work better - I replaced your each and find

```
(async() => {
  const html = await axios.get('https://www.xyz');
  const $ = await cheerio.load(html.data);
  console.log('data::',
    $(".div-previews .header-text a")
    .map(function() { return this.textContent })
    .get()
    .join("\n") // or .join(" ")
  )
})
```

Example

```js
console.log('data::',
  $(".div-previews .header-text a")
  .map(function() {
    return this.textContent
  })
  .get()
  .join("\n") // or .join(" ")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-previews">
  <div class="header-text">
    <a href="">Link 1</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div-previews">
  <div class="header-text">
    <a href="">Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div-previews">
  <div class="header-text">
    <a href="">Link 3</a>
    <a href="">Link 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in console I want to print

Comment: Can we do it in short way, without using map or return.

Comment: You have a loop and an each. I have neither. Mine is shorter than yours

Comment: getting empty, no data print

Comment: By "without return", do you mean `.map((i,e)=>e.textContent)`?   Not really saving much...

Comment: I tried with your code but not showing a single data I mean loop is not working.

Comment: @freedomn-m And I cannever remember the order. with the `function` keyword I can use `$(this)` or `this`

Comment: @mplungjan same - I have to check it every time.   The problem is that some callbacks are `(element, index)` and some are `(index, element)` and, if I recall, even ones with the same name for js/jquery are around the opposite way.  I was wondering how OP thought your code could be "shorter" or "without return" when that's the only `return`.

Comment: @freedomn-m I know you  didn't. My explanation was also directed at Faraz to show my reason for not using arrow there

Comment: I notice OP always comments "nothing is shown" (or equivalent) even when using essentially the same code they've provided.  I wonder if the cheerio.load isn't working as expected or the selectors are wrong.   As @mplungjan states - please provide a working example (all the relevant `script src=` so that we (well mplungjan...) can provide a demonstrable solution.