# Get all anchor tag text from nested div tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get all anchor tag links text and push them into array, so all links  text will be available into array, I tried using jquery but due to nested div it is unable to get each link text separately

```js
let data = []
$(".main-class").each((i, elem) => {
  data.push({
    link_text: $(elem).find(".header-text a").text()
  })
});
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div="main-class">

  <div class="upper-class">

    <section class="home-item">
      <div> some text here</div>
      <div class="header-text" >
        <a href="www.xyz.com">Link 1 text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-text" >
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="home-item">
      <div> some text here</div>
      <div class="header-text">
        <a href="www.xyz1.com">Link 2 text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-text">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="home-item">
      <div> some text here</div>
      <div class="header-text">
        <a href="www.xyz2.com">Link 3 text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-text">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </section>

  </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: `<div="main-class">` is invalid. You probably mean `<div class="main-class">`

Comment: @JeremyThille section tag are nested in main-class div

Comment: `<div class="" header-text>` is another invalid html instead is `<div class="header-text">`

Comment: @faraz I don't see the relation. It's still invalid syntax.

Comment: If you want all the anchors why not use `$("a").each` instead?

Comment: I updated my question , by mistake i kept outside i of double quotes, in my code editor it is fine.

Comment: @Reyno
 so many anchor tags are present in page, so I want to refer all section tag anchors text only.

Comment: So does it work now?

Comment: Well then target all the anchors inside the section? `$("section a").each`

Comment: @Reyno I did in my code but didn't get result, can you please write some code to get all links text.

Comment: Look, I told you twice that `<div="main-class">` is invalid, so your jQuery selector doesn't work, and it should be `<div class="main-class">`. But you keep ignoring it and wondering why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Fixing the obvious typo that's been pointed out numerous times, your code has the same issue as your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70766498/add-space-after-each-link-in-console) - **The cause** is that `.find("a").text()` will combine all the texts for all the `a`s into a single text - that's how jquery `.text()` works. You need to "loop" each "a", not using a single `.text()` call against all of them. The simplest way to "loop" and get the text for each is via .map, as provided in the provided answer to that question.

Comment: @freedomn-m I noticed your answer but unable to do it, could you please provide example by few lines of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is that `.find("a").text()` will combine all the texts for all the `a`s into a single text - that's how jquery `.text()` works.

You need to "loop" each "a", not using a single `.text()` call against all of them.

Keeping to the nearest your code (with the `.push`), the simplest way is to change the selector, rather than add an inner `.each`

```
    let data = []
    $(".main-class .header-text a").each((i, elem) => {
      data.push({
        link_text: $(elem).text()
      })
    });
```

This can be shortened to a one-line by using `.map` which handles the creating of an array and .push for you:

```
let data2 = $(".main-class .header-text a").map((i, elem) => { return { link_text: elem.textContent }}).get();
```

Updated snippet (including typo fix)

```js
let data = []
$(".main-class .header-text a").each((i, elem) => {
  data.push({
    link_text: $(elem).text()
  })
});
//console.log(data)

let data2 = $(".main-class .header-text a").map((i, elem) => { return { link_text: elem.textContent }}).get();
console.log(data2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-class">

  <div class="upper-class">

    <section class="home-item">
      <div> some text here</div>
      <div class="header-text" >
        <a href="www.xyz.com">Link 1 text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-text" >
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="home-item">
      <div> some text here</div>
      <div class="header-text">
        <a href="www.xyz1.com">Link 2 text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-text">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="home-item">
      <div> some text here</div>
      <div class="header-text">
        <a href="www.xyz2.com">Link 3 text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-text">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </section>

  </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, Now I got the perfect result, and yes you corrected me about how to loop a  in proper manner

Answer (score 1):

It work, you did mistake here : `<div="main-class">` should be `<div class="main-class">`

EDIT : if you want separate item, you rather use [map()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/);

```js
var arr = $(".main-class").find(".header-text a").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-class">

  <div class="upper-class">

    <section class="home-item">
      <div> some text here</div>
      <div class="header-text" >
        <a href="www.xyz.com">Link 1 text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-text" >
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="home-item">
      <div> some text here</div>
      <div class="header-text">
        <a href="www.xyz1.com">Link 2 text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-text">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="home-item">
      <div> some text here</div>
      <div class="header-text">
        <a href="www.xyz2.com">Link 3 text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-text">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </section>

  </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Yes I told OP twice, they ignored it twice, and keep wondering why the code doesn't work

Comment: @SKJ but i am getting in same line all the link text, instead of seprate object should be create

Comment: @faraz i edited my answer, plz next time be more clear before asking your question